# Different Spotify IDs for the same track

Tags: spotify

I am working with the Spotify API and I found a strange behavior. Some tracks have tow different IDs even the track is within the same album.

Example:
https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/0YGzsfUBgNkcfw46TvYbxj
https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3B7qxL6lZWWONOXNmEKADY (less information)

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 4):

Albums may be released several times, and tracks may be released several times but on different albums (e.g. the original and a Best Of). Even though they're in essence the same album or track, they will always have different Album URIs and Track URIs.

In your example, these two tracks are in a lot of ways the exact same track - but released on different versions of the same album. (The album may have been released in two different years, or by different companies.)

As a side-note, there's a concept of *linked tracks* in Spotify, that will equate a track that's released on several albums as the same tracks. If you attempt to play a certain track URI but it's not available in your market, Spotify will look for the same track on a different album that's available. The [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api) also exposes this functionality, read more about it the [Track Relinking Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/track-relinking-guide/).

Comment: Thanks so much. Ok I may understand it now.  I tired https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3B7qxL6lZWWONOXNmEKADY?market=CH vs. https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/3B7qxL6lZWWONOXNmEKADY If I use the market=CH the preview_URL is not empty. But in other words if I like to use the preview_url within my WebApp I just add a country where Spotify is available instead of not adding a country correct? There is no reason to ever do the call without market.

Comment: Ideally you should use a `market` value that's equal to where the user is from. If you're using an access token that a user has authorized, you could use `market=from_token`, and the resulting tracks will have a `preview_url` defined only if the track is available in the user's market. Hardcoding `market` parameter value to  `CH` would only make sense if you knew that your users were from Switzerland. If you do not have an access token, you could try to figure out where the user is from by using geolocation for the user's IP.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for this explanation. This worked out for me!